# getting square and cube of numpy and appending it

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a numpy array like below :-

```
array([[2],
       [3],
       [4],
       [5]])
```

I want to square and cube each element and then append it in numpy.
and i want the output like below

```
array([[2, 4, 8],
       [3, 9, 27],
       [4, 16, 64],
       [5, 25, 125]])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `np.power` with [numpy broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) properties -

```
np.power(a, [1,2,3])

#array([[  2,   4,   8],
#       [  3,   9,  27],
#       [  4,  16,  64],
#       [  5,  25, 125]], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: and what for the cube

Comment: The cube is included in the exponents.

Comment: oh yes my bad i get it thansk a lot :)